# How to apply the boundary condition in the derivation of the 2-point function in MAGOO?

Tags: boundary-conditions, research-level, correlation-functions, ads-cft

In the famous AdS/CFT [review](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9905111), in section 3.3.1 the authors give the two-point function of the operator $\mathcal{O}$ for which $\phi_0$ is a source, we write

$$
\langle\mathcal{O}(p)\mathcal{O}(q)\rangle=\frac{\partial^2 W\left[\phi_0=\lambda_1 e^{ipx}+\lambda_2 e^{iqx}\right]}{\partial \lambda_1 \partial \lambda_2}|_{\lambda_1=\lambda_2=0}.
$$

Now this is computed by substituting the field function
$$
\phi(x,z)=K_p(x,z)=\frac{z^2K_{\Delta-2}(pz)}{\epsilon^2K_{\Delta-2}(p\epsilon)}e^{ipx}
$$
in the qudratic term of the action
$$
S=\frac{\eta}{2}\int{d^5x\sqrt{g}\left((\partial\phi)^2+m^2\phi^2\right)}
$$
and then we perform the $z$ integral and the $\vec{x}$ integral to take the form given by equation 3.40 of the review. I managed to perform the $z$ integrals and compute the term which is multiplied by $\epsilon^{2\Delta-8}$ but I am not quite sure how we perfom the $d^4x$ integral that remains after the $z$ integrals.

The given boundary condition is $\phi_0=\lambda_1 e^{ipx}+\lambda_2 e^{iqx}$, does that mean that after performing the $z$ integral I substitute this function istead of the $e^{ipx}$?

**The essential term I calculated so far**
$$
-R^3\eta(\Delta-2)^2\frac{\Gamma(3-\Delta)}{\Gamma(\Delta-1)}\left(\frac{p}{2}\right)^{2\Delta-4}\epsilon^{2\Delta-8}\int{d^4x e^{2ipx}}
$$
I am almost certain I am handling the $x$ dependance of the field incorrectly.